# Using Application context instead of Activity Context

Tags: android, ddms

This question is an extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490493/memory-leaks-in-android-application)  , that I posted yesterday. I found a possible Memory Leak, and dealt with this the proper way. One of the memory leaks where caused by a non static inner class, more precise a non-static `Handler`.

But I am facing a new memory leak issue today. I've read this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), the essence is based around the `Context`, Activity or Application Context. 
[image]

This is the Pie chart that I got from the `Eclipse Memory Analyzer`

I have seen that there is changes in the `Remainder` of this Pie chart, after fixing issues with the `Handler`, the Remainder has increased with 10.6 MB.

But over to the Context Issue, the `Problem Suspect 2` gives me a hint where to look

```
35 instances of "android.widget.FrameLayout", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 39 218 464 (39,94%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:

•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x425aa258 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x425d9b20 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x42609258 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x4260a248 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x42925960 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x429808e0 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x429a4350 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x429d9b20 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x429e5710 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x42a28c98 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x42a51b80 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes. 
•android.widget.FrameLayout @ 0x46a8caf0 - 3 266 728 (3,33%) bytes.
```

It tells me that the memory leak occurs where I'm using a `FrameLayout`. The only place where I use a FrameLayout, is in my `Splash Screen`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    utils = new AppUtils(getApplicationContext());
    pd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pd);
    progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    version = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.version);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("firstpw", "first");
    prefEditor.commit();

    folder = new CreateApplicationFolder(getApplicationContext(), true); 
    boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    if (!isSDPresent) {
        ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.sdCardTitle),
                getResources().getString(R.string.sdCardContent),
                getResources().getString(R.string.ok), 2);
        Log.i("SDCARD: ", "Is Not Present");
        dialog.canCancelDialog(false);

    } else {
        Log.i("SDCARD: ", "Is Present");

        version.setText("Version: " + utils.getAppVersion()); 

        try {
            new ReadConfig(Splash.this, pd, progress).execute("");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Parser: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Sax: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that the memory leak occurs when I'm sending the Activity context to the AsyncTask `ReadConfig`, like this:

```
try {
            new ReadConfig(Splash.this, pd, progress).execute("");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Parser: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Sax: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO: ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

And in the ReadConfig class, I'm also using this context to start a new `Activity` in the `onPostExecute` method, which will keep this context alive.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("noConfig")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.configNotFound),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainClass.class);
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
        else if(result.equals("pathnotFound")) {

            new ErrorDialog(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.noBTFolderTitle), context.getResources().getString(R.string.noBtFolderContent), context.getResources().getString(R.string.exit), 2);

        } else {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainClass.class);
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    }
```

I need the context to start this new Activity, getting strings from the resources and so on. Is there any possible way I can do this differently to avoid the memory leak? Thanks for reading this big post, and just add a comment if you need more code or anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, probably, should try to use Application Context and not the Activity context wherever possible (it's not always possible).

To access your Application context from everywhere you can define your own application class

```
class MyApp extends Application
{
private static MyApp mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
   mInstance = this;
}

public static Context context()
{
   return mInstance.getApplicationContext();
}

}
```

Then you declare this class in your manifest

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="com.myapp.MyAppClass">
```

and use MyApp.context() wherever applicable

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I declared this class in my manifest this way: `<activity android:name=".ContextHelper"> </activity>` But when I try to using the `ContextHelper.context()` as a parameter to the ReadConfig constructor, I only get a `NullpointerException`.

Comment: @Tobias Moe Thorstensen. No you should add android:name to your application node, please, see my edited answer

Comment: @Alex  I thought private static variables cause memory leaks (they are not garbage collected)?