# Java/Android : Phonegap Contacts API memory leaks, GC_FOR_ALLOC and GC_CONCURRENT

Tags: java, android, performance, cordova, memory

I'm using phonegap for a project, and at one point I need to get the entire addressBook of the user. It works great on iOS, but on android, sometimes it takes 2 seconds, sometimes up to 20 seconds.

When it takes that much time, I'm getting a lot of `GC_CONCURRENT` and `GC_FOR_ALLOC` LogCat messages.

```
05-07 18:01:40.869: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_CONCURRENT freed 379K, 16% free 9756K/11527K, paused 24ms+23ms, total 97ms
05-07 18:01:42.650: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_CONCURRENT freed 288K, 15% free 9865K/11527K, paused 30ms+21ms, total 98ms
05-07 18:01:44.132: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_CONCURRENT freed 292K, 14% free 9972K/11527K, paused 26ms+22ms, total 114ms
05-07 18:01:46.064: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_CONCURRENT freed 276K, 13% free 10121K/11591K, paused 24ms+14ms, total 116ms
05-07 18:01:47.425: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 13% free 10273K/11719K, paused 13ms+12ms, total 65ms
05-07 18:01:49.197: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_CONCURRENT freed 335K, 13% free 10368K/11911K, paused 14ms+16ms, total 72ms
05-07 18:01:50.638: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 14% free 10405K/11975K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
05-07 18:01:51.329: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 14% free 10438K/12103K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
05-07 18:01:51.329: I/dalvikvm-heap(17847): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.436MB for 130826-byte allocation
05-07 18:01:51.379: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 14% free 10566K/12231K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
05-07 18:01:52.480: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 105K, 15% free 10487K/12231K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
05-07 18:01:52.490: I/dalvikvm-heap(17847): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.545MB for 196234-byte allocation
05-07 18:01:52.520: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 127K, 16% free 10551K/12423K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
05-07 18:01:55.303: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 233K, 15% free 10658K/12423K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
05-07 18:01:55.363: D/dalvikvm(17847): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1039K, 21% free 9837K/12423K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
```

I looked that up, and found out it was related to memory free-ing. Unfortunately it isn't depending on my code. The piece of code that generates all those messages is part of the cordova framework.

Now is there any way I could speed up the contacts fetching, or avoiding those "memory leaks" ?

The cordova project is open source, so here is the link to their github :

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova

Although this is getting too heavy for me. I'm not good enough at Java to know what I could do to avoid those memory issues.

Maybe there's just nothing I can do about it.

Thank you anyway !

Comment: FYI: It's not a memory leak, its just the dalvik vm which is doing garbage collection.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Yeah I wasn't sure about the name. Is there any way to minimize this garbage collection ? I can't have an app that takes 20seconds to retrieve contacts.

Comment: Please see my post, which I will update based on the feedback I get from you, if you comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into some problems regarding memory leaks. If you are using Eclipse, you can analyze the issue with [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). This will be much help for you. Please see the this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490493/memory-leaks-in-android-application) which contains alot of information regarding memory handling.

Just a quick sidenote; am not familiar with the phonegap library, but are you doing this operation in a thread? If not, I'd probably would try that aswell.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea if it's done in a thread or not. Phonegap allows developers to call native functions of the device, using only javascript. I call the contacts API from the JS, but then, I don't really know what happens. I posted the address of their github, I could look into it, but I'm kind of new at Java.. 
Thank you for the memory analyzer tool. I'm going to use it and I'll keep you informed.

Comment: I tried to understand MAT, but I'm swimming here. I tried to get a head dump, but it was only showing three processes, one being MAT, one being Eclipse, and one being jsp. So I dumped from eclipse, but I didn't really know when I should do it. I did it during the contacts fetching, then afterwards, but I don't know if I was supposed to do that ?

Comment: Also it looks like it's done in a thread : this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JSONArray res = contactAccessor.search(filter, options);
                    callbackContext.success(res);
                }
            });